# Cat is stressed out from new cat both female

Tags: cats, behavior, multi-pet-families, fear

Me and my family own a cat that is 4 years old. We got a 6 month old cat in April and the new cat kept casing the old cat into my room.

The 4 year old cat got scared of coming out of the room and every time we take her out she hides and/or runs away back into the room. The young cat doesn't care about the older cat anymore and doesn't chase her and now 5 months later she's still scared of her for no reason.

We tried Feliway Diffuser and the spray and it didn't work at all. Both cats have been fixed.

Comment: Only thoughts I have are to separate them for several weeks so they can start to forget each other and then reintroduce them gradually under controlled conditions as discussed in other answers. They may never be friends, especially if not fixed, but you may be able to broker a truce, at least. If not, you have to consider re-homing one.

Comment: Thank you all for your help i will start trying you methods

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that the two cats were not introduced properly. The introduction of two cats is extremely important. It takes a week to two weeks.  You can't rush the process, or they may never get along.  Your four-year-old kitty likely isn't scared. She's upset. She's depressed.  You brought another cat into *her* house.   The kitten is taking *her* attention.

You need to go through the process of re-introduction.  Be advised, this is a difficult process. It will take a lot of patience from you, and it might not work.  Here's what to do:

1. Put the kitten in a room, closed off from the other cat.  This will be difficult because the kitten is likely going to cry a lot, now that she's used to being able to roam the house.
2. Keep spending time with the kitten but behind closed doors.
3. Spend the majority of your time with your four-year-old.  If she won't come out of your room, sit on the floor and talk to her. Spend as much time as necessary on the floor next to her until she starts feeling more comfortable.  Feed her treats.  Play with her with her favorite toy.  Help her know that she is your number one cat.
4. After your four-year-old begins integrating back into the family life, start feeding her treats next to the closed door of the kitten's room.  You may have to do "treat sessions" far away from the door and then get closer and closer.  Pet your cat or talk to her, whatever she needs to feel comfortable. If the kitten cries during the sessions, ignore her.  Hopefully, your four-year-old will start sniffing under the kitten's door. This is a positive sign, even if she hisses.
5. When you feel your four-year-old has gotten comfortable in the house again, start cracking open the kitten's door, only enough for them to see each other.  Your four-year-old cat will likely run into the bedroom again. When she does, close the kitten's door, and go after your cat. Talk to her.  Pet her.  Help her know everything is OK.
6. Repeat these things until your kitten and your cat are comfortable seeing each other.
7. If you get to this point, the next thing is to have supervised sessions, with the door open.  Your job here is to pay attention to your four-year-old cat before you pay attention to the kitten, always.

If this doesn't work, I'm very sorry to tell you - but you will need to give back your kitten.  Your first responsibility is to your four-year-old. I wish you the best, and I really hope this helps you and your cat family.