# Why is my cat acting so anxious and aggressive?

Tags: cats, aggression, vocalizations, anxiety

My cat is acting anxious and aggressive. Also, he is being mean to his little sister. I have tried keeping them in my room to practice working together, but that does not help. And whenever I pick him up, he tries to bite\scratch me. He also growls at me when I pick him up.

Comment: Welcome to Pet Exchange. How long have you had your cat and how long his sister?

Comment: The cat has been here for about 1 month, but his sister has been here about 1-2 weeks.

Comment: There is a blanket list of suggestions to do but please give us more details to craft a suggestion directly applicable to your case. If you prefer a blanket list is here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28829/what-can-i-do-now-that-my-cat-is-terrified-of-me-after-i-broke-up-a-fight-involv They are all applicable to a cat under distress.

Comment: Maybe look at these two answers: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10609/cat-is-stressed-out-from-new-cat-both-female and https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10441/how-can-i-get-my-cat-to-not-be-afraid-of-me
I think you need to properly introduce your kittens and introduce yourself to your kittens since it sounds like they are afraid of you.